# How to position canvas using relative/absolute positioning

Tags: css, html5-canvas, css-position

I am having trouble setting the location of a canvas relative to another, so I wrote the following test harness.

I would expect that the positioning specified by "top" amd "left" in the div's at the top of the harness would move the origin of the canvases relative to each other.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<form id='form1' style="position:relative">
  <div id='d1' style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:1">  
      <canvas id='canvas1' width='200' height='100'>
            Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
      </canvas>
  </div>
  <div id='d2' style="position:absolute; top:50; left:50; z-index:2">
      <canvas id='canvas2' width='100' height='200'>
            Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
      </canvas>
  </div>
  <div id='d3' style="position:absolute; top:75; left:75; z-index:3">
      <canvas id='canvas3' width='50' height='50'>
            Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
      </canvas>
  </div>
</form>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<input id='btn1' type="button" onClick="demoDisplay()" value="Hide canvas with display property">
<input id='btn2' type="button" onClick="demoVisibility()" value="Hide canvas with visibility property">
<input id='btn3' type="button" onClick="demoOrder()" value="Place blue over red">

</head>
<body onLoad="loadMe()">


<script>
function loadMe()
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
    if (canvas.getContext) { // Canvas Support
       var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
       // Work with context
       var grd=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,ctx.canvas.height,ctx.canvas.width);
       grd.addColorStop(0,'#8ed6ff');
       grd.addColorStop(1,'#004cb3');
       ctx.fillStyle=grd;
       ctx.rect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
       ctx.fill();
    }   
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas2");
    if (canvas.getContext) { // Canvas Support
       var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
       // Work with context
       var grd=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,ctx.canvas.height,ctx.canvas.width);
       grd.addColorStop(0,'#C00');
       grd.addColorStop(1,'#D00');
       ctx.fillStyle=grd;
       ctx.rect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
       ctx.fill();
    }   
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas3");
    if (canvas.getContext) { // Canvas Support
       var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
       // Work with context
       var grd=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,ctx.canvas.height,ctx.canvas.width);
       grd.addColorStop(0,'#00C');
       grd.addColorStop(1,'#00D');
       ctx.fillStyle=grd;
       ctx.rect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
       ctx.fill();
    }   
}

function demoVisibility()
{
    btn = document.getElementById('btn2')
    if (btn.value==='Hide canvas with visibility property') {
        btn.value = 'Show canvas with visibility property';
        document.getElementById("d2").style.visibility="hidden";
    } else {
        btn.value = 'Hide canvas with visibility property';
        document.getElementById("d2").style.visibility="visible";
    }
}

function demoDisplay()
{
    btn = document.getElementById('btn1')
    if (btn.value==='Hide canvas with display property') {
        btn.value = 'Show canvas with display property';
        document.getElementById("d1").style.display="none";
    } else {
        btn.value = 'Hide canvas with display property';
        document.getElementById("d1").style.display="inline";
    }
}

function demoOrder()
{
    btn = document.getElementById('btn3')
    if (btn.value==='Place blue over red') {
        btn.value = 'Place red over blue';
        document.getElementById("d1").style.zIndex=2;
        document.getElementById("d2").style.zIndex=1;
    } else {
        btn.value = 'Place blue over red';
        document.getElementById("d1").style.zIndex=1;
        document.getElementById("d2").style.zIndex=2;
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add "**px**" to your style measurements. E.G `top:50;` => `top:50px;`

```
<form id='form1' style="position:relative">
    <div id='d1' style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:1">  
        <canvas id='canvas1' width='200' height='100'>
              Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
        </canvas>
    </div>
    <div id='d2' style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:50px; z-index:2">
        <canvas id='canvas2' width='100' height='200'>
              Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
        </canvas>
    </div>
    <div id='d3' style="position:absolute; top:75px; left:75px; z-index:3">
        <canvas id='canvas3' width='50' height='50'>
              Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
        </canvas>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 5):

I will make your life simple. Here is the javascript code for the same.

```
var can = document.querySelector('canvas');
  can.style.position = 'absolute';
  can.style.top = "100px";
  can.style.left = "100px";
```

Well enjoy styling the page....

Answer (score -3):

As a starter, your HTML is invalid. The content (HTML elements like `<form>`, `<canvas>` etc.) should be in a `<body>` tag inside the  `<html>` tag! The `<script>` should probably be in the `<head>`.

Also, note that the solution is using absolute positioning within an element using relative positioning.

Comment: Please edit your answer. It is very hard to figure out what you want to tell here.